# How to start the Chrome driver with Selenium (NodeJS) maximized?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, fullscreen

I want the Chrome driver to start maximized in Selenium 4 (NodeJS).

This is my Firefox/Safari solution:

```
this.driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("firefox").build();
await this.driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

But this solution does not work for Chrome.
I tried this one, but it does not work, too...

```
let chromeoptions = new chrome.Options();
chromeoptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
this.driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(chromeoptions).build();
```

Am I doing it wrong? How can I maximize the Chrome driver?

There are answers for this questions on Stackoverflow but they are out of date and/or for Python/Java and/or not working anymore in Selenium 4.

Comment: If someone also has this problem and if you are on MacOS/Linux: A bad solution: You can fullscreen Chrome by replacing "--start-maximized" with "--kiosk". But: This is the fullscreen-mode (tabs are not visible, etc.). So this is not the "maximize" solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Try this `chromeoptions.addArguments('start-fullscreen')`

Comment: This solution is better and I'll use it as long as there is no better one. But: On MacOS, this it is still not the "just maximize it - solution" as it opens the browser in a new "space". About "spaces" on MacOS: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/work-in-multiple-spaces-mh14112/mac